# PHP-CLI seems to parse JSON string from argument

Tags: json, php

Using PHP 5.3 if I send a JSON encoded string as an arugment via command line...

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/script.php {"key":"test","cache":1}
```

... and in script.php the code is:

```
<?php print_r($argv); ?>
```

I get back:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /path/to/script.php
    [1] => key:test
    [2] => cache:1
)
```

Which is completely unexpected!

Whilst I can live with this I'd like to know where this is documented by PHP so that I am 100% sure it will work like this if I pass a JSON encoded string as an argument every time.

Also arrays within the JSON string don't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Did you figure out how to parse Json from the command line parameter in PHP scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If want to use special characters in a cli argument, you should always encapse them in quotes

```
"{\"key\":\"test\",\"cache\":1}"

'{"key":"test","cache":1}'
```

Comment: Yes I figured that, but it's interesting that PHP attempted to parse the string yet this feature doesn't seem to be well known.

Comment: As you can read in your output its not parsed. On the command line you can define multiple arguments at once via list notation `{a,b,c}` (for example in `mkdir -p path/to/{folderA,folderB}`). The JSON-object looks similar and is therefore misinterpreted. As far as I know its not PHPs fault, but just the way CLI-calls "work".